# Can Angular Directives depend on xml transformations by xslt?

Tags: angularjs, xslt

I'm trying to create an Angular Directive menu with as little javascript as possible (I'm using angular so that config files can be specified on an app by app basis in custom directive). To create the menu, I have an xml file being translated by xslt into an html page. When I view the xml in a browser, it comes out styled as I want it. CSS alone is sufficient to provide the functionality I want.  When I cite this html page as a templateURL for an angular directive, it does not load saying :Template for directive 'siteMapMenu' must have exactly one root element.

Of course the message is correct, but removing the nodes isn't an option in xslt processing, correct?

sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet  type="text/xsl" href="Views/Shared/SiteMapScout.xslt"?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">...(rest of sitemap spec)
```

sample XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:t="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
>

  <xsl:output  omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html" indent="yes"/>


      <xsl:template match="/">


        <div class="span-20 last" style="margin-left:100px;height:25px; border-top: solid 1px Gray; width:79%">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/CSS/jqueryslidemenu.css" />

            <style type="text/css">
              .showSubMenu{
              visibility: visible;
              }



              .hover:hover a{
                visibility: visible;

              }


            </style>
<div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu" style="margin-left: 0px;">

<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="/t:mvcSiteMap/t:mvcSiteMapNode/t:mvcSiteMapNode">

            <li class="hover">

              <a  href="#">
              <xsl:value-of select="./@title"></xsl:value-of>
              </a>



              <xsl:if test="count(./t:mvcSiteMapNode) &gt; 0">


                  <ul >

                  <xsl:for-each select="./t:mvcSiteMapNode">

                    <li  >
                      <a href="#" >
                          <xsl:value-of select="./@title"></xsl:value-of>
                      </a>
                    </li>

                  </xsl:for-each>
                  </ul>

              </xsl:if>

            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </ul>
</div>


</div>


    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample Directive:

```
; (function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('scout').directive("siteMapMenu", siteMapMenu);

    function siteMapMenu() {

        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: "ScoutSitemap.xml",
            //templateUrl: "TestMap1.html",
            controller: [
                '$scope', '$filter', siteMapController
            ]
        };

    }

    function siteMapController($scope, $filter) {
        $scope.ShowMaintenance = false;
        $scope.ShowReports = false;
        $scope.ShowFileDownload = false;
        $scope.ShowHelp = false;

    }

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following methods and accessed them appropriately from the directive's controller to achieve what I was shooting for.

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename) {

    var xhttp = {};
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
    try { xhttp.responseType = "xml" } catch (err) { } // Helping IE11
    xhttp.send("");

    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult($scope) {
    var xml = {};
    var xsl = {};
    var xhttp = {};
    var xsltProcessor = {};
    var resultDocument = {};
    xml = loadXMLDoc("ScoutSitemap.xml");

    xsl = loadXMLDoc("Views/Shared/SiteMapScout.xslt");
    if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
    {
        ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
        document.getElementById("myfill").innerHTML = ex;
    }
        // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {

         xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
         xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);

        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
        $scope.resp = resultDocument.textContent;

        document.getElementById("myfill").appendChild(resultDocument);
    }
}
```